# JS | Проверка на цифры

Tags: javascript

Помогите с проверкой. Как проверить, состоит ли переменная только из цифр?

```
var cifri = "764923"; //Рандоманая, всегда из 6 цифр - не пропустит
var cifri = "ferrf6"; //Должно пропустить потому что тут не только цифры, но есть еще и буквы
```

Если в переменной находятся только цифры, тогда возвращаем false

Если в переменной находятся цифры и буквы, тогда true

```
if(cifri.length != 6 && ... ) {
console.log("Не 6 цифр, все хорошо");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через простое регулярное выражение:

```js
const hasOnlyDigits = (v) => /^\d+$/.test(v);

console.log(!hasOnlyDigits('12345'));
console.log(!hasOnlyDigits('2e10'));
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но не судьба сделать так: `const notOnlyDigits = (v) => !(/^\d+$/.test(v))`?

Comment: Мне такой вариант меньше нравится. Читается в коде хуже. Например, если я захочу использовать эту функцию в обратную: `!notOnlyDigits(...)` - читается плохо. Но это лишь мое мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
let result = Number.isNaN(Number(ЗДЕСЬ_СТРОКА_С_СИМВОЛАМИ))
```

Ещё вариант:

```
let result = !isFinite('ЗДЕСЬ_СТРОКА_С_СИМВОЛАМИ');
```

Comment: isFinite(2e64); // true

Comment: да, экспонента тут всё портит %)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let check = (string) => !!((string.match(/[a-z]/) || string.match(/[A-Z]/)) && string.match(/[0-9]/))

console.log(check('123')) // false
console.log(check('abc')) // false
console.log(check('123abc')) // true
```

Всё легко и просто, просто идёт проверка на то есть ли маленкие буквы  или большие, а потом проверка есть ли в строке числа.

Comment: [...'120456'].every(e => +e) => false

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Извиняюсь? Вы уверены, что ваш код рабочий?

Comment: Это ваш код, а не мой :) Если среди цифр есть 0, то вернет false

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey тот код который вы предоставили **в комментарии** (своём) невозможно воспроизвести, вы его вообще тестировали? *P.S. исправил свой ответ т.к. он не соответствовал требованиям вопроса*

Comment: Я не предоставлял код. Это ваш **первый вариант ответа**. Я указал вам, что если в строке будет 0, то результат будет false. Указал это как `=> false`. Не надо ничего воспроизводить. Правильно сделали, что исправили ответ.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey ой, простите, не сразу понял что вы имели в виду, чаще, пожалуйста, используйте подсветку текста, иначе боюсь ещё найдутся те кто неправильно поймут вас. (Кстати вы пожалуй первый у кого я прошу извинений на этом форуме)